# Let $\{v_1, v_2, v_3 \}$ be a basis for a vector space. Prove that the set $\{av_1, b v_2, c v_3 \} $ is a basis when $a, b, c ≠ 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $\{v_1, v_2, v_3 \}$ be a basis for a vector space. Prove that the set $\{a v_1, b v_2, c v_3 \}$ is a basis when $a, b, c ≠ 0$.

I am aware of the basic properties that make a spanning set a basis but proving the statement above seems to be above my capabilities at this moment. Could you help me prove it? Thanks.

Comment: You need two things (i) the set is linearly independent, (ii) the set spans the vector space. Which of them is bothering you?

Comment: @AnginaSeng thank you for your comment! Well at this point (where I've just started learning about basis and been trying out some practice problems), the problem is deciding on how to approach. I am aware of the two conditions but how would I be able to apply that to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Put the vectors in a matrix as columns,  the original 3 vectors are known to be linear independent therefore the det is not zero, now multiply each column by the corresponding scalar, the det still not zero - the vectors are independent. 3 independent vectors are base to the space here.

Comment: @Alon That would be overkill

Answer (score 3):

The new basis spans the vector space:

Every element of $V$ is of the form $v=k_1v_1+k_2v_2+k_3v_3$ for some scalars $k_1,k_2,k_3$. The $v=\frac{k_1}{a}av_1+\frac{k_2}{b}bv_2+\frac{k_3}{c}cv_3$. Thus the new basis generates $V$.

The set is linearly independent:

Assume that we have scalars $k_1,k_2,k_3$ such that $0=k_1av_1+k_2bv_2+k_3cv_3$. Linear independence of the old basis shows that $k_1a=k_2b=k_3c=0$. But then $k_1=k_2=k_3=0$. Therefore the new basis is linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! If you do not mind, could you explain the second part again? I find it challenging to comprehend your explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Remember that a set is linearly independent if the only linear combination of that set that yields zero is the linear combination where all scalars are zero. Therefore, in order to proof linear independence, you need to take an arbitrary linear combination that sums to zero and proof that the coefficients are zero. That is how I started. With a linear combination of the new basis which yields zero. Then I showed that the coefficients had to be zero. I just noticed a mistake in the proof. I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that your scalars are in some field.
You only need to prove that the set $\{av_1,bv_2,cv_3\}$ is linearly independent as any linearly independent set of $n$ vectors in an $n$ dimensional vector space is a basis and in your case, $n=3$ because there is a basis which consists of $3$ elements.

To prove that $\{av_1,bv_2,cv_3\}$ is linearly independent,suppose $\alpha_{1}av_1+\alpha_{2}bv_2+\alpha_{3}cv_3=0$ and observe that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis and none of $a,b,c$ are zero.

Can you prove from here that $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3=0$?